# Halting JavaScript program operation upon error condition?

Tags: javascript

So in my app when a particular condition occurs, I want to display an alert and then stop program execution.  I read somewhere that this can be done with a throw() but I'm unable to make that work.

Here's what I've tried:

```
function check_for_error(data) {
    try {
        if ( <error condition> ) { 
            throw "error"; 
        }
    } catch(e) {
            alert('error occured'); 
                // I want program execution to halt here but it does not, 
                // it continues within the calling code
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try throwing error from the catch block and then handling it in the callee method.  And essentially exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must re-throw the exception:

```
...
catch(e) {
    alert('error occurred');
    throw(e);
}
```

Comment: Ok got it to work by doing the above, then in the calling function putting the call in a try / catch, with the catch empty.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should throw another error in the catch block. Or not catch the initial error at all.

Currently, the following happens:

```
<error condition me>
throw "error"
catch error and  Show alert
```

To "halt" the execution, you have to add `throw e` after the alert (in the `catch` block):

```
catch(e) {
    alert('error occurred');
    throw e;
}
```

If your function is called from within another try-catch block, you also have to apply a similar mechanism to that block.

Answer (score 0):

and also you can

```
function check_for_error(data) {
    try {
       //WHEN ERROR OCCURES
    } catch(e) {
            alert('error occured'); 
                // I want program execution to halt here but it does not, 
                // it continues within the calling code
            throw(e);
            return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw only will stop execution of synchronous rutines, For example if you made an asynchronous http request it will execute the callback function regardless of a previous error.

Throw doc from [w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_throw.asp):

> Syntax
>
> throw exception
>
> The exception can be a string, integer, Boolean or an object.